# How can I find out which process was stopped by RansomWhere?

Tags: macos, encryption, logs, malware

I use [RansomWhere](https://objective-see.com/products/ransomwhere.html), a tool to protect from ransomware. I have OS X Yosemite.

As far as I understand, RansomWhere just warns me whenever an app tries to encrypt data. It's up to the user to judge whether they trust a process or not. (And whether the application is one which *should* need to encrypt data.) The user is given the choice of `Allow` or `Terminate` each time there is a warning. It has warned me about several apps I trust and that I figure did need to encrypt data, and I have simply clicked `Allow`.

However, just now I got a warning about a process I don't know what was. The message said "is encrypting data", so I figuredd I had to hurry, so I just clicked `Terminate` immediately after seeing that I wasn't sure what the process actually was. After clicking `Terminate`, the dialogue box disappeared, and I heard nothing more from RansomWhere regarding the issue.

Now, I want to know what this process actually was and what was going on. I don't remember the details given in the message, just that I wasn't sure which process it was. I wish I would have taken a second to take a screenshot before pressing `Terminate`, but unfortunately, I didn't.

How can I find out which process this was and what was going on?

Answer (score 1):

According to [RansomWhere's](https://objective-see.com/products/ransomwhere.html) own site the data is stored in

- `/Library/RansomWhere/installedApps.plist` - a list of applications already present on the system.
- `/Library/RansomWhere/approvedBinaries.plist` - a list of binaries explicitly approved by the user.
- `/Library/RansomWhere/whitelist.plist` - a list of safe binaries (that often legitimately create encrypted files).
- `/Library/RansomWhere/graylist.plist` - a list of system binaries that are not explicitly trusted.

However, because an app that was terminated is by design not remembered, it will not appear in any list.

> The following list summarizes the 'allow' and 'terminate' actions
>
> - 'allow'   Tells RansomWhere? it's ok to let the process continue running. This will be persistently remembered; you'll never be alerted
>     about this binary again.
> - 'terminate'   Tells RansomWhere? to kill the process. As this action is a little more drastic, RansomWhere?, (by design) will not remember
>     such actions. Thus if the terminated process is ran again, it will
>     cause another alert.

You could check Console to see whether it generated an event at the time - I can't test that as I've never run RansomWhere.

Comment: Should I search in console? Or look it up by time? In either case, how would I recognize the event?

Comment: You'd have to see what kind of trace RansomWhere leaves in console - if anything - then map it to the time you saw the dialog.